# Assign a user input string as a new variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, reflection

I have a text  field in which the user inputs some text. I'd like to take the first word of that text and turn it into a global variable name for an object holding the rest of the string content. More string content will be added to object later, so internal indexing inside the object is required.

```
var textInput = $('#inputText').val();
var splitString = textInput.split(" ");
var firstWord = splitString[0];
```

This is where I get stuck. How please do I create a new object with the string referenced by firstWord as the object's reference?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could either use Eval(...) or window["objectName"] =

Comment: An object doesn't have a name... Do you mean that you want to create a variable with that name, containing a reference to an object? Would it be a local or global variable?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean't Guffa. I understand that eval is bad practice Serge?

Comment: eval is almost evil :) In the sense you should validate user input to prevent code injection… in your case It seems you just need to grab the first token of a string, operation that could be done quite safely… but… if you mean to pollute the global scope (i.e. windows) than… It should definitively a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
globalUserObjects = {};

var textInput = $('#inputText').val();
var splitString = textInput.split(" ");
var firstWord = splitString[0];

globalUserObjects[firstWord] = {};

// Now later you can add stuff to it

globalUserObjects[firstWord]["firstName"] = "John";
globalUserObjects[firstWord]["lastName"] = "Smith";
```

Comment: You are right of course. Thank you very much. I couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: No problem.  Let me know if you have any followup questions.